# Ordering issues loading JSON files into custom child modules in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I made a custom child module that is building a variety of unique AWS resources (NIC, EIP, Key-pair, EC2 instance, Security group, Glacier vault, IAM user/group/policy, etc.).  In our line of business, when a new customer is onboarded they will receive one of these child modules, so each of the module instances is slightly unique and standalone, but they all consist of the same components.

I thought it would be cool to have JSON definition files that define the unique attributes for each of these child modules, then let Terraform do the rest of the work by loading each of the JSON files into the child module... And for the most part, this is working great.  However, I've recently discovered an ordering issue with how Terraform chooses to load the JSON files into modules and does comparisons against the current state file.

Here is my folder structure:

```
main.tf
providers.tf
variables.tf
instances/
|_
  server01.json
  server02.json
  etc...
modules/instance/
|_
  main.tf
  variables.tf
  providers.tf
  outputs.tf
```

The **root module** *main.tf* file will load all of the JSON files into child modules using a for_each expression:

```
locals {
  json_data = [for f in fileset("./instances/", "*.json"): jsondecode(file("./instances/${f}"))]
}

module "instance" {
  for_each = { for k,v in local.json_data: k => v }
  source = "./modules/instance"
  server_name = each.value.server_name
  server_dns = each.value.server_dns
  server_private_ip = each.value.server_private_ip
  server_customer = each.value.server_customer
  <<more input properties defined...>>
}
```

**The problem** -- Let's say that tomorrow, the customer associated with *server01.json* decides to leave our service.  I thought an easy way of offboarding their child module in Terraform would be to label the JSON file with a different extension (like .bak) so the *main.tf* file would ignore loading this into the json_data list and see that all the resources associated with that instance are no longer required.
What actually occurs is Terraform will compare the *server02.json* file to the state file of **module.instance["0"]** (since it is now the first in the list of JSON files) and see a whole bunch of differences and things to destroy/recreate.  It will also then recognize that **module.instance["1"]** has been removed (since there's no longer 2 JSON files), and want to delete all of the resources associated with the *server02.json* file.
This is a problem because it requires destroying and rebuilding the EC2 instance but there is a lot of data on these instances that must persist.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to handle a scenario like this?
Is there a way to have the **module.instance[]** state file associate the list with the names of the JSON files, instead of their order?
Was a custom module the wrong approach for this use case?

Any inputs or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform's [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) mechanism uses the keys of the provided map as the keys to identify individual instances of the resource.

In your case, you've used a `for` expression to project a list into a map by using a string representation of the element index as the key, and so Terraform is in turn effectively using the element index as the instance key, following your instruction to do so.

If you want Terraform to track the instances using some other keying scheme, you'll need to construct a map which has the keys that you want Terraform to use. To meet the requirement you stated, that means a map from filename to the JSON data, which you could perhaps construct like this:

```
locals {
  instances = tomap({
    for fn in fileset("${path.module}/instances/", "*.json") :
    fn => jsondecode(file("${path.module}/instances/${fn}"))
  })
}
```

Because this result is already a map, it's directly compatible with `for_each` and so you no longer need the secondary `for` expression to project it:

```
module "instance" {
  source   = "./modules/instance"
  for_each = local.instances

  server_name       = each.value.server_name
  server_dns        = each.value.server_dns
  server_private_ip = each.value.server_private_ip
  server_customer   = each.value.server_customer
  # ...
}
```

This will produce module instances with addresses like the following:

- `module.instance["server01.json"]`
- `module.instance["server02.json"]`

This means that if you edit an existing file then Terraform will understand that as a change to the input variables of the existing instance, whereas if you add a new file then Terraform will understand it as adding a new instance of the module, which I think matches what you were hoping for.

Comment: This is brilliant and exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!

I understand now what I was doing wrong.  I'm still new to the declarative syntax in Terraform...  It's hard to get out of a regular imperative coding mindset.